# What, exactly, does Android DatePicker.setMinDate() and DatePicker.setMaxDate() do?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am working on an app in which I would like the user to select dates, so I am using the `DatePickerDialog`.

I want the user to be able to select dates **only within a certain range**, so I figured I would use the `DatePicker.setMinDate()` and `DatePicker.setMaxDate()` methods to limit their choices. This is what I used:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this);
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(viewModel.getMinDate().toEpochSecond());
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(viewModel.getMaxDate().toEpochSecond());
datePickerDialog.show();
```

In a particular instance of my app, the `viewModel.getMinDate().toEpochSecond()` gives me **2019-07-15T18:18:44.829Z**, and the `viewModel.getMaxDate().toEpochSecond()` gives me **2019-07-16T15:12:39.563Z**, which are both valid (type `Long`) dates of **1563214724** and **1563289959** respectively.

However, when my DatePicker dialog opens, I get this:

[image]

I cannot select any dates whatsoever.

If, however, I were to try this:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this);
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime() + 1000L);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

I get this:

[image]

Again, still cannot select any dates.

Date inconsistencies aside, I do not see how `setMinDate()` and `setMaxDate()` are affecting anything at all. I am still able to select dates outside of my `min` and `max` range. Reading the developer reference, it says:

*Sets the minimal date supported by this NumberPicker in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in TimeZone#getDefault() time zone.*

What does that even mean *"supported by this NumberPicker"*??? Obviously, it doesn't mean *"limits what a user can and cannot pick"* as I cannot pick anything anyway.

So, again, what, exactly, does DatePicker.setMinDate() and DatePicker.setMaxDate() do?

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks to [@MobileMon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085736/mobilemon) this is the solution that I used:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(minDate.getYear(), (minDate.getMonthValue() - 1), minDate.getDayOfMonth());
return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your min and max dates are not even a day a part (2019-07-15 & 2019-07-16). There's no choice for the user to make. Need to make a greater range for date picking.

In the second example where you say new Date().getTime(), same scenario. Try setting it to like '9/7/2016' - '12/3/2019' for example

Comment: My date `2019-07-15T18:18:44.829Z` is an `OffsetDateTime` which I converted using `toEpochSecond` and confirmed to be accurate by using one of the many online unix timestamp converters.

Comment: Ok? You still need to open the range to something larger than 1 day between the min and max. I'm not sure what you don't understand

Comment: Meaning one day is 15 JULY 2019 and the next is 16 JULY 2019 ... there should be, at least, two selectable dates on the `DatePicker` correct?

Comment: Try removing the time portion so set the date to 2019-07-15T00:00:00.000Z and see what happens

Comment: or set it to one second the previous day

Comment: I used your advice and put my solution in my original post. Thanks!